# String to RegEx conversion

Tags: php, regex

```
(name eq "xxxx" and user:(post.id eq 6 and post.post eq "testing") and data eq "Hello World!")
```

I have this above string and I want to filter it through RegEx to get the following output:

```
[
 [
   "name eq "xxxx"",
   "user" => [
       "post.id eq 6",
       "post.post eq testing",
   ],
   "data eq "Hello World!"",
 ],
 [
   "name",
   "user" => [
        post.id,
        post.post
   ],
   "data",
 ],
]
```

I have tried the following regex solution

```
/([\\w\\.]+)[\\s]+(?:eq)[\\s]+(?:"(?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*"|\\d+(?:,\\d+)*(?:\\.\\d+(?:e\\d+)?)?|null)/i
```

And got the value

```
[
[
  "name eq "xxxx"",
  "post.id eq 6",
  "post.post eq "testing"",
],
[
  "name",
  "post.id",
  "post.post",
],
]
```

Comment: You want too much.

Comment: *Stack Overflow Wouldn't Be Very Welcoming*. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Kyslik I didn't get you?

Comment: @revo Would it be welcoming now?

Comment: Rarely people care. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated. @revo

Comment: You have added an attempt, but you have not added the *actual requirements*, and we do not know why you chose that pattern and not another. The question is still unclear/too broad. What are the input string format specs? I doubt you can do that with a regex unless you are sure there are static elements that can always be relied upon for extraction. Usually, for these kinds of texts, parsers are written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I dint check on the regex though

```
$input="(name eq \"xxxx\" and user:(post.id eq 6 and post.post eq \"testing\") and data eq \"Hello World!\")";

$inarr = [":(", ")","("];
$reparr   = [" and ", "", ""];
$input=str_replace($inarr, $reparr, $input);

$resultarr = explode(" and ", $input);

echo '[
      [
$resultarr[0]' . ',' .
      '"' . $resultarr[1] . '" => [' . 
   $resultarr[2] . ',' . 
   $resultarr[3] . ',' .
'],
   "' . $resultarr[4] . '",
 ],
 [
   "name",
   "user" => [
        post.id,
        post.post
   ],
   "data",
 ],
]';
```